# Cargar datos de sql a un list view VB

Tags: vb.net

Buenas quisiera que se carguen los datos de mi tabla Rubro como columnas.
Pero hasta el momento no me logra visualizar en mi list view.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código actual:

```
   Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ListView1.Columns.Add("Ultima Cuota", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Numero de Credito", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Numero de Cuota", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)

        conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=conexion;Initial Catalog=BD;User ID=usuario;Password=contrasena")
        Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
        strQ = "select top 2 Descripcion from credito..Rubro WHERE IdRubro NOT IN (41,42,44,45,1056,1057,1058,48,43) "
        cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Rubros")
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        'Dim mycb As New CheckBox
        ListView1.View = View.Details
        ListView1.CheckBoxes = True
        ListView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = ListView1.Columns.Count - 1


        'ListView1.Controls.Add(mycb)
        ' adding the columns in ListView
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                Dim LSet = Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString())
                ListView1.Columns.Add("Check", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Center)

                LSet.Width = 208

            Next


                'Now adding the Items in Listview
                'For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                'For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                'itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
            Next
            'ListView1.Controls.Add(mycb)
            'Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
            'Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
            'Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Por lo que veo podrias desplegar tu informacion en forma tabular por lo que creo que un datagridview te seria mas util en este caso que un listview a no ser que requieras hacer una vista muy personalizada de la informacion que presentas de la tabla, de ser asi puedes ligar el dataset directo a la tabla ya que esta soporta un datasource de forma directa.

Comment: La recomendacion que da @JesusRodríguez es cierta, pero bueno, igual publicare una solucion para ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cargar tu ListView usando tu **base de datos SQL**, necesitaras primero hacer una consulta... y esa misma consulta, almacenarlo dentro de un objeto **DataTable**, asi finalmente solo lo tendras que recorrer con un **For Each** (o cualquier ciclo repetitivo que te sea mas comodo). En lo personal prefiero este para recorrer DataTables.

*Voy a utilizar como base de datos Microsoft Access... igual no te preocupes por esto, porque el procedimiento de extraer datos es exactamente igual.*

1. *Primero que nada...* Define una clase base con el cual vas a realizar tus consultas... Yo tengo la mia ya definida llamada **Acceso**, con su respectiva **conexion**. Solamente voy a necesitar usar la siguiente funcion:

   ```
   Protected Friend Function SelectQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
       Dim tabla As New DataTable
       con.Open()
   Try
       comando = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
       adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(comando)
       adapter.Fill(tabla)
       comando.Dispose()
       adapter.Dispose()
   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Error en la consulta: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
   End Try
       con.Close()
       Return tabla
   End Function
   ```

En que consiste esta funcion... pues como veras, esta funcion es de tipo **DataTable** y necesitara un parametro que sera la **consulta** (String) a tu base de datos.

- Primero, la funcion declara un objeto de la clase DataTable y abre la
  conexion a la base de datos.
- Nos adentramos luego dentro de un **Try Catch**. Inicializando un atributo de clase llamado comando, instancia de la clase OleDbCommand (que en tu caso, al estar usando SQL, debe ser **SqlCommand**), pasandole como parametro nuestra consulta y nuestra conexion.
- Luego de eso, inicializamos otro atributo de clase llamado adapter, instancia de la clase OleDbDataAdapter (que en tu caso, debe ser **SqlDataAdapter**), pasandole como parametro nuestro objeto OleDbCommand.
- Usamos el metodo *Fill*, pasandole como parametro nuestro objeto DataTable. Aqui nuestro adaptador rellenara de datos usando la consulta recibida y se conectara con tu base de datos gracias a la conexion pasada.
- Eliminamos objetos (comando/adapter) y liberamos memoria con **Dispose**, ya que el deber de cada uno ha concluido.

Ahora pasamos al siguiente paso, que es muy sencillo, cuando vayamos a solicitar datos para nuestro ListView. Como ejemplo, voy a capturar todos estos datos de esta tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Public Class DemoClassListView
Dim admin As New Acceso
Private Sub DemoClassListView_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListView1.View = View.Details

    ListView1.Columns.Add("Id_Cliente", 75, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Empresa", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Direccion", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Correo", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)

    For Each itm In admin.SelectQuery("SELECT Id_Cliente, Empresa, Direccion, Correo FROM Cliente").Rows
        Dim obj As New ListViewItem(itm(0).ToString)
        obj.SubItems.Add(itm(1).ToString)
        obj.SubItems.Add(itm(2).ToString)
        obj.SubItems.Add(itm(3).ToString)
        ListView1.Items.Add(obj)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Nota que primeros tuvimos que construir nuestra ListView sin datos. Y luego proceder a recorrer nuestro DataTable, quiero que le prestes mucha atencion a esta linea de aqui porque es clave:

```
For Each itm In admin.SelectQuery("SELECT Id_Cliente, Empresa, Direccion, Correo FROM Cliente").Rows
```

Este es la declaracion de nuestro ciclo for each. En donde creamos un objeto temporal que capturara los datos contenidos en las filas de nuestro DataTable.

Dentro del ciclo:

```
Dim obj As New ListViewItem(itm(0).ToString)
    obj.SubItems.Add(itm(1).ToString)
    obj.SubItems.Add(itm(2).ToString)
    obj.SubItems.Add(itm(3).ToString)
    ListView1.Items.Add(obj)
```

Como tenemos capturada la fila en nuestra "variable temporal" **itm**, le señalamos seguidamente la columna de acuerdo a su indice... funciona exactamente igual que los arreglos. Las columnas que selecciones en tu consulta, siempre empezaran desde 0.

*Id_Cliente = 0, Empresa = 1, Direccion = 2, Correo = 4, ColumnaQueSigue = 5... y asi sucesivamente.*

Igualmente, si tienes pereza de hacerlo de esta forma, puedes simplemente escribir el **nombre de cada columna**:

```
Dim obj As New ListViewItem(itm("Id_Cliente").ToString)
        obj.SubItems.Add(itm("Empresa").ToString)
        obj.SubItems.Add(itm("Direccion").ToString)
        obj.SubItems.Add(itm("Correo").ToString)
        ListView1.Items.Add(obj)
```

Y nuestro producto final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo recomendable generalmente, al trabajar con este nivel de base de datos, es usar **DataGrids**... ni siquiera tendrias la necesidad de construir las columnas... puedes seleccionar las columnas que desees... hacer un ***JOIN*** a tu gusto sin tener que andar añadiendo columnas anteriormente... por ejemplo...

Comment: me podrias mandar  el codigo fuente a mi correo pflores@qapaq.pe
            ya que no me logra salir por favor

Comment: Gracias hermano me sirvio de monton tu codigo, le agregue otras lineas de subrutinas y me salio super